# Is there a way to prevent direct file download under cloudflare or other way?

Tags: c#, cloudflare, windows-server-2012-r2

I have about 1 Terabyte of pdf files where if you know the path ofthe file you can download it even if you are not logged on the web application. The web is under Cloudflare and I was wondering if there is a rule that you can use to prevent direct download if you are not logged.

Should I use a file transfer web service? Do I have to move the files necesarilly?

I have the files on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the web application is on WebForms C#.

We are migrating to another system but I need to protect the files for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block the access to the entire directory with a WAF rule e.g.

(http.request.uri.path contains "/files" and http.host eq "domain.com")